# Filter add ArrayList<object> to HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList, its hierarchy has 3 levels. Category, Forum, ChildForum. 
But Forum and ChildForum, they have the same attributes (most important attributes are nodeId, and parentNodeId).And a coupe Forums don't have any ChildForum inside it.

```
Category------
             |
            Forum---------
             |           |
             |        ChildForum--------
             |                         |
             |______________________Thread
```

So I want to find a way to binding them into listviews, and onClickItem, check out which Forum **has child or not**, so i can navigate the view to the right fragment

This is what i have done now:

```
    nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>(); //nodeList contains Category, Forum, and ChildForum
    forumNodeList = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
    childList = new ArrayList<Node>(); // temp array
    forumChildNodeList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();
```

Fill data

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
            if (nodeList.get(i).getParent_node_id().equals(nodeId)) { //nodeId = categoryId
                forumNodeList.add(nodeList.get(i));
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < forumNodeList.size(); j++) {
                if (forumNodeList.get(j).getNodeId()
                        .equals(nodeList.get(i).getParent_node_id())) {                     
                    childList.add(nodeList.get(i));
                    // Log.d("childList", "" + childList.size());
                    forumChildNodeList.put(
                            forumNodeList.get(j).getNodeId(), childList);
                }
                forumChildNodeList.put(forumNodeList.get(j).getNodeId(),
                        childList);
            }
        }
```

setOnClickItem:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            if (forumChildNodeList.get(
                    forumNodeList.get(position).getNodeId()).size() > 0) {

                //Fragment Transaction to ChildForumFragment
            } else {

                //Fragment Transaction to ThreadFragment
            }

        }
    });
```

When i show log in onClick. it looks like all HashMap with forum id have the same ChildForum. In fact some of them don't have any childForum.
I know for sure, For-loops and the if-conditions have something wrong. or maybe I am missing something? Please help! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry ! I updated error! Hashmap forumChildNodeList return data is wrong !

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. It's condition problem:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        if (forumChildNodeList.get(forumNodeList.get(position)
                    .getNodeId()) != null) {

            //Fragment Transaction to ChildForumFragment
        } else {

            //Fragment Transaction to ThreadFragment
        }

    }
});
```

array should be **ArrayList!=null** instead of **ArrayList.size()>0**